# Getting some raw data response from server in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am sending some data to the server in android, but as a resonse i am getting some raw data which consists javascript and html which again disappears within few seconds, is it response from server that data is sent, if not so then what i have to do?, here i'm using AsyncTask class

Here my class

```
  private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost  httppost = new HttpPost("http://182.18.144.140:80");
                      String responseBody="";

         try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LAT", lat));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LON", lng));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     try {

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                      responseBody= EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


                    String resp = response.getStatusLine().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), resp, 5000).show();

      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", 5000).show();
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.i("HTTP Failed", e.toString());
            }           

            return responseBody;
        }



        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Updated Server!"+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
           }
```

Comment: You have to post some code or how far did you get, otherwise hardly will someone help you

Comment: @NKN Here is my code please check this

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "i am getting some raw data which consists javascript and html which again disappears within few seconds"?

Comment: In my emulator screen it is displaying like this and again disappears when i run it

Comment: Please, describe the issue more clearly. Now it's very difficult to understand that is the problem.